# Как проинициализировать свойства объекта класса? Имя свойства должно браться из словаря

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
class di:
    booklist = "DI"
    data = {'nickname'  : "nickname",
            'in'        : "in",
            'category'  : "int",
            'log'       : "bool",
            'name'      : 'notempty',
            'inversion' : "bool",
            'ton'       : "s5time",
            'tof'       : "s5time",
            'module'    : "notempty",
            'cleath'    : "notempty",
            'device'    : "notempty"}


    def __init__(self, row, nrow):
        i = 0
        for key in data
            if check(row[i], data[key], "Лист: " + booklist + " Строка: " + str(nrow)):
                self.[key] = row[i]
            i = i + 1
```

Есть ли в Python какая-то инструкция, которая сработала бы как `self.[key]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[setattr](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#setattr) кажется наиболее подходящей для такого случая. Или можно работать напрямую с `__dict__`